# Angular 8 Is there a way to stop triggering [disabled]="somefunc()" function on button on every keystroke?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8, angular-material-8

Here is the code snippet:

```
 <button mat-icon-button [disabled]="isNextStepDisabled()" (click)="nextStep()">
        <mat-icon style="cursor: pointer">navigate_next</mat-icon>
 </button>

isNextStepDisabled() {
  console.log('In isNextStepDisabled');
}
```

I am using Angular 8 with material stepper.

Noticed that isNextStepDisabled() function is being called every key stroke in the form (actually in any form once the step is active). How not to trigger it but only when user moves away from some fields?

Comment: Consider changing change detection strategy https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy

Comment: Can I specify changeDetectionStrategy for each control in a component? I need other form fields to trigger as keystroke?

Comment: Changedetection is per component. Depending on the case you can try by not using a function but an Observable. For example [disabled]="nextButtonDisabled$|async" and put you logic in a stream.

Comment: Thank you ZellB.and Alexander both of these are good suggestions. Let me try out and will report back.